# cassandra-jdbc and Ebean, can they work together?

Tags: jdbc, playframework, cassandra, ebean

Admitting I am not a Avaje Ebean expert or a JDBC expert either. I use play framework and Ebean in the "normal" use cases (H2 and mySQL basically) and they perform fine for me.

I found recently about the cassandra-jdbc driver project and was wondering if I could naively make them work together. So I tried and, once I turned off evolutions, I got a SQLFeatureNotSupportedException because cassandra-sql force autocommit always on.

I wanted to know if there is a way to make them work together since the driver claim to be Jdbc compliant and Ebean should be able to work with that. Is there something in the way Ebean use the drivers that make this impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the cassandra-jdbc driver is jdbc complient, at the moment its not possible to use cassandra as the backend for your playframwork @Models.

There are a few projects trying to implement support for NoSql, although not explicitly cassandra, in the play framework, have a look at [**siena**](http://www.sienaproject.com/index.html).

Also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743850/how-to-configure-play-framework-project-to-use-kundera-with-cassadra) might be a useful reference.